# SelectList's -Setting value with an IF condition does not work

Tags: selectlist

I tried the below and it works:

```
<apex:selectList  value="{!abc}" rendered="{!IF(abc=='true','Yes','No')}" />
```

but

```
<apex:selectList  value="{!IF(abc=='true','Yes','No')}"/>
```

does not even compile with an error:
Result:

> [COMPILE FAILED]: (ClaimExpense) Unknown property
>   'IF(abc=='true','Yes','No')'  (Line: 1, Column: -1)

Other tags like outputText do accept IF conditions in the value attribute.
Does it mean this is something special with selectList that it does not accept formula for the value attribute?

Answer (score 3):

SelectList value attribute needs to bind to a controller setter property. It represents the value chosen by the user from the picklist.

OutputText value is merely displaying text, the source can be a controller getter property or a formula expression that resolves to a string.  What you can't do, however, is to have  a formula expression that dynamically derives a setter property.

As an aside, the expression you are using in the rendered can be simplified to:

```
rendered="{!abc}"
```

as rendered attribute need only be a Boolean.